# problem in #defining cout?

Tags: c++

A friend of mine told me that this code has some problems:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
#define cout printf   
int main(){
    cout("cout");
}
```

He didn't give me the reason and asked me to figure it out which I couldn't. The code seems to be working fine, what could possibly be wrong with it?

Comment: It's wrong because you're redefining `cout` to be an alias of `printf`. And the two are completely different animals.

Comment: It's not wrong technically.  It's wrong morally.  I think that's what your friend meant.

Comment: It is almost certainly going to become wrong technically as well, and likely sooner rather than later.

Comment: "Seems to be working fine" is completely different from "a good way to do it or likely to work in other circumstances".

Comment: "Seems to be working" is like "I crossed the street without looking, wasn't run over by a bus". Wanna try again?

Comment: Redefining existing names  with the preprocessor is always wrong.

Comment: thanks all. now I know why this is wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know the Standard forbids defining names (with #define) declared in any standard library header.

Found this in n3290 ($17.6.4.3.1)

> 17.6.4.3.1    Macro names                                                                  [macro.names]
>
> 1 A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not #define or #undef names declared in any standard library header.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is true, but I'll be snookered if I can find proof.  I know it applies to keywords at the very least, but `cout` is hardly a keyword.

Comment: Names are not keywords, and keywords can never be declared or defined. As such it certainly applies to `cout`.

Comment: So in other words, if he removed the `#include <iostream>` line, his program would be legal, just confusing.  As of now, it needn't even compile.

Comment: It's legal to write an infinite recursive loop that locks up your application.

Comment: @Prasoon, @Dennis: I don't know where you find it exactly, but mine n3290 copy says "A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not #define or #undef names declared in
any standard library header.", so removing `<iostream>` doesn't make it a valid program since it still includes cstdio.

Comment: @Prasoon: yes, see my quote. Please verify that you actually quoting n3290. I can found your quote in C++98, but all C++0x drafts I look at have the quote I gave.

Comment: @ybungalobill: That is correct, I completely misread that statement to only apply to the one included.  I even thought the wording was weird, since standard library headers can include other standard library headers, so there'd effectively be no way to know if your program was well formed on any given compiler.  The actual wording makes much more sense :-)

Comment: OTOH, redefinition of `malloc` has a rich history that probably predates C++.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It has problem.

Since its C++, one may *habitually* write `cout << 1000` which would be an error in this case, but which is otherwise very normal in C++.

What next? Are you trying to define this:

```
#define scanf cin

//so that you can use it as
scanf >> variable; //not so kewl.
```

My advice is :

Don't try to change the meaning of such names. What will you get by doing so, after all? Nothing.

Answer (score 2):

While you may argue that this code "seems to be working fine", consider a few years down the line when your 7-line source file is a 7-hundred-line source file and you are not the only maintainer.

You've moved on from writing C-style `printf` statements in C++ source files and you add (or another maintainer adds) the following line of *perfectly valid C++*:

```
    cout << "What is wrong with my perfectly valid C++ code? " << endl;
```

And your compiler reports:

```
test.cpp:699: error: invalid operands of types ‘int ()(const char*, ...)’ and ‘const char [29]’ to binary ‘operator<<’
```

A whole world of pain!

Answer (score 1):

It's got maintenance problems, because you'd redefined well-known features to work differently.  So no other programmer will want to work on this code.

Similar:

```
#define MULTIPLY(a, b) (a + b)

#define FIVE 12
#define THREE 3

int main(void)
{
    return MULTIPLY(FIVE, THREE);
}
```

It gives the right answer, but is totally unmaintainable.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You have declared `main` as returning `int`, but have not included a `return` statement. You should add a `return 0;` to the end of the `main` function.</strike> In C++ you don't have to `return` a value from `main`, but it's good style.

Oh, and don't `#define cout printf`, it's really confusing. It may not be technically *illegal*, but it's not nice for whoever comes later to try to maintain your code.

Comment: If you don't return anything from main, the compiler will implicitly return 0.  That's not an error.